# On an example of an idempotent which is not a projection

Tags: functional-analysis, projection, idempotents

I am working through a solution of the following exercise in Conway's functional analysis:

> Let $\mathscr{H}$ be the two-dimensional real Hilbert space $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\mathscr{M}=\{(x,0):x\in\mathbb{R}\}\subseteq\mathscr{H}$, and $\mathscr{N}=\{(x,x\tan{\theta}):x\in\mathbb{R}\}\subseteq\mathscr{H}$, where $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$ is fixed.  Find a formula for the idempotent $E_\theta$ with range $\mathscr{M}$ and kernel $\mathscr{N}$.  Also show that $\|E_\theta\|=(\sin{\theta})^{-1}$.

I am very confused with this question. I will write my try can you please help me why I can't get the solution?

My questions :

1- $Ε_\theta$ is an operator s.t. it transforms all points of $\mathbb R^2$ to the $x$-axis. So intuitively $Ε^2_\theta=Ε_\theta$. But how one write an explicit formula for $Ε_\theta$. Isn't it $Ε_\theta (x,y)=(x,0)$ and if so it doesn't depend on $\theta$ then?

2- $\ker (Ε_\theta)$ is the set of point s.t. $Ε_\theta(x,y)=(0,0)$ then it must be the $y$-axis, then why it is $\{(x,x \tan\theta): x \in \mathbb R\}$?

3- how $\|Ε_\theta\|=(\sin \theta)^{-1}$? Calculating  $\|Ε_\theta\|=\sup Ε_\theta$ depends on two things to know before that : is sup taken on the circle in $\mathbb R^2$? what is explicit formula for $Ε_\theta$ so that to know on what supremum is taken?

4- this exercise is designed to indicate an example of an idempotent which is not a projection? $\ker E$ is the $y$-axis and $\operatorname{ran} E$ is the $x$-axis so how $\ker E = (\operatorname{ran} E)^{\perp}$ does not hold when it holds?

Comment: Please don't link to photos of questions.  They can't be read by e.g. Google, so people can't find your question via search engines.

Comment: Also, [you can create lists](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#simple-lists) by "1.", etc.

Comment: @JacobManaker, thanks! there is a program that turns picture to written latex, not possible to install and not able to find it online. Can you guide me how to turn pic to text without writing? i have exam and have not much time.

Comment: @JacobManaker, so you wrote it? I mean you typed the text and didn't use a software? I didn't ask you to type it (either or not a subtle way), I asked you do you know a software to turn screenshot to latex? And if there is no software, so I will type it

Comment: A basic mathjax tutorial can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @4.5h I was surprised when I saw that someone had downvoted : then I go up to vote and realize *I* had downvoted this. Funny, that, because I was looking to upvote, perhaps a mouse slip since I'm used to voting often. I'll be careful next time, my "-1" is now a +1.

Comment: I didn't like the community at all. I was not expecting this kind of behaviour For some picture that I have an exam do I delayed writing it as latex **for a few days**, I received an unkind words. I am deleting my account.

Comment: @4.5h I am sorry if you have received unkind words. However, I want to say this as well : just like shifting into a new apartment and meeting new people and making new friends, we all need to be patient on this site and realize that even our first few interactions are not going to go as we thought. However, when we persist, see the reasons why things are what they are, and then act, then there is a possibility of two things happening (1) We actually realize what was being said was for our good (2) We can help others go down the same path and improve. I sincerely hope everything improves.

Comment: @4.5h You wrote a very detailed attempt of your question, so why wouldn't anyone vote up? But providing information via links has a very simple problem : links break. So it's important that the most important parts of the question are not provided in links, but rather in the question. Jacob's intent was to actually improve your question. So no one is putting you down because you didn't have a perfect question. In fact, Jacob actually made your question more viewable, and also bumped it into the front page where it was viewed and up voted more. We are all trying to help each other here, first.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon, but he could be more polite in his (now removed) comments.

Comment: @4.5h I see! So the question is about politeness. Yes, perhaps the poster could have been more polite. In fact, the comment could have either been removed by a flag, or by the poster himself , so the site itself acknowledges that they should have been polite. I still think, though, that the intentions of that person was to make sure that your question became self-contained, was more neatly presented, and finally got more attention. It goes both ways. So I'm sorry on their behalf. I want dedicated people to stay on site, and I feel that you will benefit from regular visits to this site...

Comment: ... just like the person who edited your post as well. Both of you had intentions that overall looked at improving the site : one by editing a question to fix a broken link, and the other by reviewing the edit, asking a question that was well-written according to the guidelines, and taking the time to be active in the comments. We are all people with good intentions, @4.5h , so let bygones be bygones. Proceed with the same vigour with which you wrote this content. I know we are yet to see the best of you on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator is $E((x, y) ) = ( x - \dfrac{y}{\tan \theta} , 0 ) $

Its kernel is the set $ \{(x, y) | x - \dfrac{y}{\tan \theta} = 0 \}$ which is exactly the
set $ \{ (x, x \tan \theta) \} $

Thus it follows that $ ker E \ne (ran E)^\perp $

The norm of the operator is $\sup  | (\cos \phi - \dfrac{\sin \phi}{\tan \theta } | $

which is $ \sqrt{ 1 + \dfrac{1}{\tan^2 \theta} } = \dfrac{1}{\sin \theta} $

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer, but some background that's likely to be useful:

Let $u$ and $v$ be non-zero vectors in a Euclidean space, viewed as column matrices, and let $v^{t}$ denote the transpose of $v$.

The *inner product* $v^{t}u = u^{t}v$ is the dot product $u \cdot v$ viewed as a $1 \times 1$ matrix.

The rank-one matrix $uv^{t}$, also known as the the *outer product* of $u$ and $v$, has kernel the set of vectors orthogonal to $v$ and image the line spanned by $u$. Further, if $u \cdot v = 1$, then $uv^{t}$ is idempotent.

In case some exercises help:

1. Show the image of $uv^{t}$ is the set of scalar multiples of $u$, and the kernel is the set of vectors orthogonal to $v$.

> For every vector $w$, we have $(uv^{t})w = u(v^{t}w) = (v \cdot w)u$, which is a scalar multiple of $u$. Further, this product is $0$ if and only if $v \cdot w = 0$, if and only if $w \perp v$.

2. Show $uv^{t}$ is idempotent if $u \cdot v = 1$.

> We have $(uv^{t})^{2} = (uv^{t})(uv^{t}) = u(v^{t}u)v = (u \cdot v)uv^{t} = uv^{t}$.

3. Find the standard matrix of $E_{\theta}$. (Geometrically, $E_{\theta}$ is a "slant projection", like casting a shadow on the $x$-axis when the sun is not directly overhead.)

> Hint: Take $u = (1, 0)$ and $v = (1, -\cot\theta) = \frac{1}{\sin\theta}(\sin\theta, -\cos\theta)$, noting that $u \cdot v = 1$ and $(\sin\theta, -\cos\theta) \cdot(\cos\theta, \sin\theta) = 0$.